# Gradient Boosting - Price Forecast based on Month

Tags: python, gradient, xgboost

## What I am trying to achieve.

I want to forecast Natural Gas prices under the column "NG Open" based on other parameters in the data set below for all Contract Months. I am using XG Boosting algorithm and somehow at the output I can only see twenty five values predicted and cannot interpret which contract month they would apply to. I am using KFold Validation to be on safe side instead of train_test_split

```
  Contracts     NG Open  NGHigh  NGLow   NGLast    NGVolumes   

  2018-12-01    3.907   4.384   3.907   4.272       0 
  2019-01-01    3.917   4.408   3.917   4.291       264295  
  2019-02-01    3.800   4.267   3.785   4.148       155303          
  2019-03-01    3.515   4.007   3.496   3.865       51299       
  2019-04-01    2.735   2.829   2.704   2.793       73226           
  2019-05-01    2.632   2.691   2.602   2.667       54540       
  2019-06-01    2.638   2.719   2.634   2.692       34269
```

## Code.

```
  import pandas as pd
  from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor 
  from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
  from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

  dataset = pd.read_excel("C:\Futures\Futures.xls")
  dataset['Contracts'] = dataset['Contracts'].str.rstrip('(E)')
  dataset['Contracts'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Contracts'])
  dataset  = dataset.set_index('Contracts')
  dataset1 = dataset.values

  X = dataset1[:,0:5]
  y = dataset1[:,0]

  gbrt=GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100) 
  kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7, shuffle = True)
  results = cross_val_score(gbrt, X, y, cv=kfold)
  print("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))

 gbrt.fit(X_train, y_train)
 predictions = gbrt.predict(X_test)
 print(predictions)
```

## Code Output

Accuracy: 99.16% (1.51%)

[2.90288328 2.48242494 2.63815259 2.56852281 2.56852281 2.74960132
 2.58107653 2.80135512 2.67153137 3.54629023 2.50640456 2.5038906
 3.05384458 2.55023831 2.85925744 2.73849325 2.74080839 2.79646487
 2.89086965 2.52839402 2.63251226 2.85012468 2.87403014 2.52685035
 2.73180843]

How can I correlate the output of 2.9028838,2.48242494.. to contract month and second month and so on is my first question and second question is how can I generate the same output for all the rows. Total Rows are 100 with contract months up-to 1st March 2027

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone can answer this?

Comment: XGBoost makes one prediction for each data point in your `X_test` matrix. What are you trying to predict here? The contract month?

Comment: Well you seem to be subject matter expert and thanks for taking time to read my post but here is what I am looking for. Based on the model accuracy I am looking to see how xgboost to provide a price of $2.90 for December 2018, 2.48 for January 2018 , 2.638 or some type of predicted values for months under the column NG Open based on data from other columns. The prices would be presented sequentially for all the months under column NG Open.

Comment: If you want to see how XGBoost makes decisions you can try looking at the text model output by using dump_model. I suggest you start by setting num_estimators to 1 and study the output for a single tree.

Comment: Wow. this is a segway to something new. Do you know any link where I can look up the information that you are telling? So essentially speaking I cannot predict all the 100 rows of NG Open based on the data from other columns.

Comment: You can but it would be overfitting your model to the data. If you really want to learn about modeling I suggest you go through the [Elements of Statistical learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/), or at least see how [linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) work before trying out complex models like GBRTs.